# Is there a bestiary of "derived 2-vector spaces"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories, topological-quantum-field-theory, a-infinity-algebras

The appendix "A bestiary of 2–vector spaces" of [Bartlett, Douglas, Schommer-Pries, Vicary, "Modular categories as representations of the 3-dimensional bordism 2-category"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06811) analyzes a number of symmetric monoidal (weak) 2-categories each deserving the name "the 2-category of 2-vector spaces". The main result is that in all the analyzed 2-categories, the sub-2-categories of fully dualizable objects all agree. (The subcategories of 1-dualizable objects vary depending on the 2-category.)

What would such a bestiary look like if instead of "vector spaces" we worked with "derived vector spaces", maybe meaning the $\infty$-category of chain complexes? Some options for "the derived 2-category of derived 2-vector spaces" might be various $(\infty,2)$-categories of linear $(\infty,1)$-categories, for various choices of functors.

**Question 0:** Has anyone assembled a "bestiary" of such options?

**Question 1:** Is there a (known or conjectured) bestiary-type result identifying the fully dualizable sub-$(\infty,2)$-categories of the different options?

**Question 2:** How do the derived and underived bestiaries relate?